# cannot pass commandline args to globale installed node package via bin shortcut

Tags: node.js, command-line, npm, symlink

I try to write a commandline app with node and want to install it with `npm install -g`

After that it is not possible to read out the process.argv array.

I tried this :

```
// print process.argv
process.argv.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + val);
});
```

When I call `node /bin/myprog parm1` it works.
When I call `myprog parm1` no parms are passed.

Any idea to get the parent caller process.argvs? I am Using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also on Windows 7, and I've created the following test package here and it works perfectly: https://gist.github.com/gustavohenke/5657481

Check if you're not forgetting about the first line in the `mybin` file.

Also, I strongly recommend for you to use [nopt](https://github.com/isaacs/nopt) or [commander](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/) for parsing your CLI options.
They turn this into an very easy and cool task!